# Jetpack Compose find parents width/length

Tags: android, layout, android-jetpack-compose

I want to explicitly retrieve the value of the `fillMaxSize()`.
Suppose i have:

```
        Box(Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.Yellow)) 
        {
    var size = ?
    Box(Modifier
                .size(someSize)
                .background(Color.Blue))
        {Text("Test")}
```

I want to change the size of my second Box multiple times (will probably stem from some viewmodel) and then reset it to maxSize.

How can I do that? I don't know any 'getMaxSize()'-method?

Answer (score 53):

If you really need the raw size value, you can use the following code:

```
    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }
    
    Box(Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Yellow)
        .onSizeChanged {
            size = it
        }
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .then(
                    with(LocalDensity.current) {
                        Modifier.size(
                            width = size.width.toDp(),
                            height = size.height.toDp(),
                        )
                    }
                )
                .background(Color.Blue)
        ) { Text("Test") }
    }
```

But note, that it's not optimal in terms of performance: this view gets rendered two times. First time second box gets size zero, then the `onSizeChanged` block gets called, and then view gets rendered for the second time.

Be especially careful if using `remember` in top level views, because changing state will trigger full view stack re-render. Usually you want split your screen into views with states, so changing one view state only will re-render this view.

Also you can use `BoxWithConstraints` where you can get `maxWidth`/`maxHeight` inside the `BoxWithConstraintsScope`: it's much less code and a little better on performance.

```
BoxWithConstraints(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Yellow)
) {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .size(
                width = maxWidth,
                height = maxHeight,
            )
            .background(Color.Blue)
    ) { Text("Test") }
}
```

But usually if you wanna indicate size dependencies, using modifiers without direct knowing the size should be enough. It's more "Compose" way of writing code and more optimized one.

So if you wanna you second box be same size as the first one, just use `.fillMaxSize()` on it too. If you wanna it to be some part of the parent, you can add fraction param. To make second box size be half size of the first one, you do:

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(fraction = 0.5f)
) { Text("Test") }
```

If you wanna different parts for width/height:

```
Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(fraction = 0.3f)
        .fillMaxHeight(fraction = 0.7f)
) { Text("Test") }
```

Comment: fillMaxWidth(fraction) was what I was looking for, thanks Phil ;)

Answer (score 24):

In your first `Box` you can use the [**`onGloballyPositioned`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/OnGloballyPositionedModifier) modifier to get the `size`.
It is called with the final `LayoutCoordinates` of the Layout when the global position of the content may have changed.

Then use `coordinates.size` to get the size of the first `Box`.

```
var size by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero)}

Box(
    Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.Yellow)
        .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
            size = coordinates.size.toSize()
        }
        Box(){ /*....*/ }
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `BoxWithConstraints` :

```
@Composable
fun Card(/* ... */) {
    BoxWithConstraints {
        if (maxWidth < 400.dp) {
            Column {
                //...
            }
        } else {
            Row{
              //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives you a `maxWidth` and a `maxHeight` to create your logic. More info here on [this Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/adaptive).

***Hope it helps!***

Answer (score 1):

```
Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {
                var parentSize by remember {
                    mutableStateOf(Size.Zero)
                }
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .aspectRatio(1f)
                        .background(Color.Green)
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(100.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.Center)
                            .background(Color.Red)
                            .onGloballyPositioned {
                                //here u can access the parent layout coordinate size
                                parentSize = it.parentLayoutCoordinates?.size?.toSize()?: Size.Zero
                            }
                    ) {
                        Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                            Text(text = "parent size  = $parentSize")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image]