# Set height of child elements equal to highest other element that are contained by Row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

is it possible to force a Row to redraw its children to have a height of largest child, when height of children is not fixed?

```
Row {
    Box {

    }

    Box {
        // second child has larger height, recompose first child to match height of the second child? 
    }
}
```

I end up with something like: [image: problem]

I think it is because Row measures each child individually but I would like first child to be recomposed to match the height of the second one, once second one is added into Row. Is this possible?

Comment: This answer here will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67141583/9715339

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose find parents width/length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67138343/jetpack-compose-find-parents-width-length)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can add `Modifier.fillMaxHeight` to all child views and limit their height to the largest of them by adding `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` to the parent view:

```kotlin
Row(
    Modifier
        .padding(10.dp)
        .height(IntrinsicSize.Max)
) {
    Text(
        "First",
        fontSize = 20.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.Gray)
    )
    Text(
        "Second",
        fontSize = 30.sp,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(Color.LightGray)
    )
}
```

Result:

[image]